# Encapsulate a Java application's document file as a package on OS X

Tags: java, macos, bundle, info.plist

I am writing application specific documents from a Java application. These documents are basically a collection of related files / database within one directory. On OS X I would like to **have this directory appear opaque as if it was one document file**, similar as RTFD hides an RTF text file along with associated resources (such as pasted graphics). I understand this concept is called [package](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html).

For example, imagine this structure:

```
MyDocument.ext/
   MetaData.xml
   Database/
     Db0
     Db1
```

etc. I would like this to appear in the Finder as a document `MyDocument`, not a directory.

I will be able to produce an app bundle for my Java application, so that could contain a document descriptor in its Info.plist.

How would I tell the OS X to treat my documents (directories) this way? Via the Info.plist, or do I need to execute some particular terminal program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW1), indeed only an entry in the application's plist is needed: In the document type entry, the key `LSTypeIsPackage` must be included with value `"true"`:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>Foobar Document</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array>
      <string>foobar</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
    <string>true</string>       <!-- !!! -->
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
    <string>foobar.icns</string>
  </dict>
</array>
```

I had to copy the application to `/Applications` for the Finder to recognise my new file type, but then it worked, and the directories ending in `.foobar` are shown as opaque files.